# jQuery on success, reload the page and then append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, append

I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'edit_slides.php',
        data: { user_id: user_id },
        success: function() { 
            location.reload(); 
            $('#messageContent').append('<p>success</p>'); 
        }
    });
```

What happens right now is that it appends and then reloads real quick so it loses the message.

Now, I could take out the reload and it will append but in order for my changes to take affect, the page needs to be reloaded.

Is there anything else I can do? I want to show a success message after reloading the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`location.reload()` will reload your page, which creates a new request to your server and the browser then loads the response. You could add a parameter to the query string for the message, e.g.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'edit_slides.php',
        data: { user_id: user_id },
        success: function() { 
            window.location = "?message=success";
        }
    });
```

Then in server side code, you could display the message if the parameter exists. In ASP.NET MVC, it would look like this:

```
@if(Request["message"] == "success")
{
    <p>success</p>
}
```

If you don't have server side scripting available, you can also [parse the querystring with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/26226).

Answer (score 2):

You can have some delay before you reload the page. Try this

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'edit_slides.php',
        data: { user_id: user_id },
        success: function() { 
            $('#messageContent').append('<p>success</p>'); 
            setTimeout(function(){
               location.reload(); 
            }, 500);
        }
    });
```

Comment: 500ms wouldn't really give the user a sufficient amount of time to read the message.

Answer (score 2):

Send it to a location but with a hash in the url to indicate a success:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'edit_slides.php',
    data: { user_id: user_id },
    success: function() { 
        window.location = window.location + "#success";
    }
});
```

Now when the page loads, check for the hash:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.hash) {
        $("#messageContent").append("<p>success</p>");
    }
```